# Simple 1-N FK relationship woes

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I'm trying to get a simple 1-N FK relationship working with DataNucleus JDO. I have classes GridDO and GridColumnDO with relevant getters and setters. I'm trying to establish that a grid has multiple columns. The entity_attribute (GridColumn) table has a FK column (named entity_id) to the entity (Grid) table's PK (also named entity_id). I worked off of [the example code](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/one_to_many_collection.html#fk_uni) on the DataNucleus website. I can load the GridDO object, but when I try to get the columns, I get

```
Iteration request failed : SELECT 'com.mycompany.myapplication.data.GridColumnDO' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,A0.DISPLAY_NAME,A0.COLUMN_ORDER,A0.PROPERTY_NAME,A0.ENTITY_ID,A0.ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ID,A0.VALUE_TYPE FROM ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE A0 WHERE A0.ENTITY_ID = ?
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Iteration request failed : SELECT 'com.mycompany.myapplication.data.GridColumnDO' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,A0.DISPLAY_NAME,A0.COLUMN_ORDER,A0.PROPERTY_NAME,A0.ENTITY_ID,A0.ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ID,A0.VALUE_TYPE FROM ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE A0 WHERE A0.ENTITY_ID = ?
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #1 has not been set.
```

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong? I've been searching and banging at this for a while now, with no real luck. This is an excerpt from package-mssql.orm:

```
    <class name="GridDO" identity-type="application" table="entity">
        <field name="id" primary-key="true">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </field>
        <field name="columns">
            <collection element-type="com.mycompany.myapplication.data.GridColumnDO"/>
            <element column="entity_id"/>
        </field>
        ...
    </class>

    <class name="GridColumnDO" identity-type="application" table="entity_attribute">
        <field name="id" primary-key="true">
            <column name="entity_attribute_id"/>
        </field>
        ...
    </class>
```

Comment: You can't reuse "entity_id" column in GridColumnDO for the FK of the relation in GridDO. Map your 1-N FK uni relation as per the docs that you refer to (which you're currently not doing).

Comment: Thanks for replying. It would be helpful if you told me what I was actually doing wrong. I've been trying to find what I messed up, and I'm just not seeing it. FYI, and I'll edit the post, both tables have an entity_id column. On entity, it is the PK. On entity_attribute, it is the FK.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I pulled the gridId field from the GridColumnDO table. Still seeing the same issue. I will edit the post to reflect the updated ORM file.

Comment: @DataNucleus Also, I posted a similar question on your forum (http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7642_offset,0). That post has a patch file of test-jdo, and Andy has been going back and forth with me. I don't want you guys to be duplicating effort on the same problem. I was hoping somebody unofficial might have an idea, that's why I posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that PersistenceCapable and PrimaryKey must either both be identified via annotations or both be identified via metadata. I had PersistenceCapable in an annotation and PrimaryKey in my .orm file.